# Git: How to merge 3 branches into another only one? (not Master)

Tags: git

I have 3 branches. Can you hint me please, how to merge three branches (where is one based on another) into the new branch (not Master)?

Answer (score 1):

Create your target branch from any of the branches you want to merge...

```
git checkout branchA
git checkout -b target
```

Then merge the other 2 branches into that

```
git merge branchB
... solve any merge issues
git merge branchC
... solve any merge issues
```

Done!